# Selenium (browser.find_element(by=By.PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT) error

Tags: python, selenium

I need to find a partial link button on the page and click on it. But it gives me an error.

**Code:**

```py
button = browser.find_element(by=By.PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT('/watch')).click()
```

[Link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xVZ1hGklkMc)

**Error:**

```
button = browser.find_element(by=By.PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT('/watch')).click()
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 problems here:

1. Instead of

```py
browser.find_element(by=By.PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT('/watch'))
```

it should be

```py
browser.find_element(By.PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT('/watch'))
```

2. In case you want to click on that element on the same line you should not try to put the result to `button` object. Because `browser.find_element(By.PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT('/watch'))` returns an object of web element so you can click on it with `.click()` method. However `.click()` method itself returns void i.e. nothing. So your code can be

```py
browser.find_element(By.PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT('/watch')).click()
```

or

```py
button = browser.find_element(By.PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT('/watch'))
button.click()
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the wrong way

```
button = browser.find_element(by=By.PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT('/watch')).click()
```

You should use this :

```
button = browser.find_element(By.PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT, "/watch")
button.click()
```

Also, If You see the method signature is

```
def find_element(self, by=By.ID, value=None):
```

It is expected to pass `By`  then separate that with the actual locator.

Also, I would recommend having WebDriverWait (ExplicitWait) for this use case.

```
button = WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT, "/watch")))
button.click()
```

You will have to import these as well.

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Answer (score 0):

You were close enough. The actual implementation is:

```
self.find_element(by=By.PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT, value=link_text)
```

So you need to pass two parameters,

- The `by` parameter`:

  ```
  By.PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT
  ```
- The `value` parameter within quotes:

  ```
  "/watch"
  ```

So your effective line of code will be:

```
browser.find_element(By.PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT, "/watch")
```

---

Finally, *`click()`* doesn't returns anything, so if to try to assign it to a variable, it will be always *`NULL`*. So better to drop it.

So your working line of code will be:

```
browser.find_element(By.PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT, "/watch").clcik()
```

---

Ideally to invoke *`click()`* you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable/59130336#59130336) for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

```
WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT, "/watch"))).click()
```

**Note** : You have to add the following imports :

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```